# How to change value of element without binding in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What's the best way to do something like this in AngularJS without data binding?

```
document.getElementById('divid').value = 'Change Text to This';
```

I know I can achieve it with {{value}} but I have default values for SEO purpose and hence I need to change it without binding, for example,

```
<div id="divid">Default text</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: You can try `ng-init`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do data binding for  this {{}} also you can use ng-bind.

Comment: <p ng-bind="player.name"></p>

Answer (score 0):

In angular you can fetch an element using `angular.element()`

In your case, Try

```
var ele = angular.element('#wrapper');
$compile(ele);
```

For this to work you need to inject `$compile`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use translate function:

```
<div id="divid">{{ _("Default text") }}</div>
```

function:

```
$.scope._ = function(text) {
    return 'Change Text to This';
};
```